# Photon kick manually added player from the game

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking, photon

I added few bots in the game as players by

```
PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.AddPlayer(bot); //bot is derived from Photon.Realtime.Player
```

now when the bot loses the game I want to kick him so I am calling

```
PhotonNetwork.CloseConnection(bot);
```

but PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.Players, PhotonNetwork.PlayerList, PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.PlayerCount nothing is being affected I am not able to remove the bots from the game from the master client

Answer (score 0):

So you can not add bots as players in pun Player refers to a specific connected player. One you can send events to, etc
So I will have to make my own custom list which consists of bots and players. I won't be able to use any of the playerslists or dictionary Photon provides.